# Fix annoying auto-indentation in PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Perhaps it's "bad practice," but I like to keep my indentation in a scheme like this:

```
<tag att-one="abc" att-two="def" att-three="ghi"
        att-four="jkl" att-five="mno" att-six="pqr"
        att-seven="stu">
    <next-tag/>
</tag>
```

In Java code, I do basically the same thing:

```
 public void doSomethingImportant(arg1, arg2, arg3,
         arg4, arg5, arg6) {

 }
```

In PyDev, when I newline while working inside of a method argument list, I get a massive indent to the position of the beginning of arguments:

```
def my_amazing_cool_houdini_method_of_awesomeness(arg1, arg2,
>>>                                               arg3):
    pass
```

How do I make it stop indenting so far forward? Is there a way to configure it to only indent a tab-equivalent or two (as determined by my tab-space conversion ratio)?